# Keyboard shortcut for adding tags to Pocket; chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

After using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> shortcut to save a webpage to Pocket, how do I enter the 'add tags' input field without having to mouse into it? Is there a keyboard shortcut for instantly adding tags this way? I'm using Vimium, and hitting <kbd>f</kbd> and then typing the highlighted text for the tag input field I can get into the text input field with my cursor but only for a split second so that it fades out before I get to finish inputting my tags.

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to Pocket Support on Twitter, and currently there is no sure way of doing this.  Some sites with no tab ordering (very rare) will do this with a single tab.  Below is the reply I got:

> We've been considering making this an option in our Extension, so thanks for letting us know that this would be helpful! Right now, for some sites, you can press Tab to focus on the tags field, but it doesn't always work.